# Why is DNS TC useful?

Tags: networking, dns, ip

Migrated from https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37055/why-is-dns-tc-useful

In studying for a computer networks exam, I started reading the DNS message format, and found something that I don't follow.

I don't see why the TrunCation (TC) flag is needed.

> TrunCation - specifies that this message was truncated due to length greater than that permitted on the transmission channel.

DNS Messages are sent using UDP, that in turn uses IP.

Considering that IP supports fragmentation to solve the issue of a packet being bigger than the MTU, why is that flag needed? Why do you even have to truncate the message at all?

Thanks everyone

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/587625/why-dns-through-udp-has-a-512-bytes-limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by Michał Politowski pointed to the answer. DNS has a 512 byte limit on UDP (the transmission channel). My problem was assuming that transmission channel meant the layer 2 protocol, not UDP.